# Yii2 afterSave. Using changedAttributes show error

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I have this weird error in my Yii2 Model's AfterSave Function

When I do this

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    if(!$insert):
        print_r($changedAttributes);exit;
        $this->prepareMail(self::MAIL_APPROVE);
    ;
}
```

I get

```
Array ( 
 [reason_for_travel] => 1 [project_id] => [billable] => 1  
 [advance_required] => 0 [status] => 2  ) // See it contains 'status'
```

But when i do this

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    if(!$insert):
        $status = $changedAttributes['status']; // this line shows error
        if($status == Self::STATUS_CONFIRMED):
           $this->prepareMail(self::MAIL_APPROVE);
        ;
    ;
}
```

$status = $changedAttributes['status']; This line shows error

Error is "Undefined index: status"

What am I not seeing ?

Comment: try extending `$changedAttributes->status;`

Comment: @InsaneSkull  Error : "Trying to get property of non-object". Also Doc says its array.

Comment: you were not getting `status` in array..............

Comment: your array is not valid says undefined offset.

Comment: Yes ,  error text implies what you are saying. But when i print it out , array has the index 'status' . When i remove the exit point and use the value , issue arise. !!!!!

Comment: What version of php are you using? That code gives a syntax error on 7.

Comment: Guys Leave It. I will move the logic to controller.

Comment: is it possible that afterSave() is called multiple times? once without status?

Comment: @D.Mill Though i found a  workaround and completed the task. I checked the code again after seeing your comment. And you are right about it.  save() is called again inside afterSave() which in turns calls afterSave() ,  this time without  'status'. Thanks , wont make the mistake next time ;)

Answer (score 3):

use this lines:

```
if(!$insert):
  $status = isset($changedAttributes['status']) ? $changedAttributes['status'] : 0); // this line shows error
    if($status == Self::STATUS_CONFIRMED):
       $this->prepareMail(self::MAIL_APPROVE);
    ;
;
```

$changedAttributes contains the old values of the modified fields but only modified fields, valid if exist with "isset" skip errors.

Answer (score 0):

How to check is an attribute has changed after saving

```php
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    //isAttributeChangedAfterSave
    var_dump(array_key_exists('name', $changedAttributes) && $this->name != $changedAttributes['name']);

    //...
}
```

**Note** that `isAttributeChanged()` does not work in `afterSave()` because after saving, `$this->oldAttributes` is assigned new values.