# yii2 how to make a notification by e-mail to the user after changing his status

Tags: email, notifications, yii2, status

yii2 how to make a notification by e-mail to the user after changing his status?? Help me, Please!

Model

```
class Applicants extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $file;
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'applicants';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id', 'type_passport_id', 'passport_number', 'date', 'expiration_date', 'passport_path', 'diplom_number', 'diplom_path', 'phone_number', 'mobile_number', 'country_id', 'city_id', 'address', 'faculty_id', 'spec_id', 'stage_id', 'training_id', 'dormitories_id'], 'required'],
            [['user_id', 'type_passport_id', 'country_id', 'city_id', 'status_id', 'faculty_id', 'spec_id', 'stage_id', 'training_id', 'dormitories_id'], 'integer'],
            [['passport_number', 'mobile_number', 'applicants_comment'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
            [['expiration_date'], 'string', 'max' => 120],
            [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf'],
            [['passport_path', 'diplom_path', 'address'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['diplom_number'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['phone_number'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['user_id'], 'unique'],
            [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

Help me, Please!

Comment: Add function `changeStatus($newStatus)`, which will be reposnsible for changing status of user, and inside handle sending email aswell.

Comment: can explain more

Comment: Use function `changeStatus($newStatus)` (which you need to write) to change user statuses. Inside this function you can send email to user after saving his status.

Comment: hey did the answer worked out for you , do mark it as selected correct if it helped you out

Answer (score 1):

You can use `afterSave($insert,$changedAttributes)` to check for changed attributes and send the email.

According to the [**`DOCS`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail) $`changedAttributes` parameter has old values of `attributes` that had changed and were saved. You can use this parameter to take action based on the changes made for example send an email when the `password` had changed or implement `audit` trail that tracks all the changes. `$changedAttributes` gives you the old `attribute` values while the active record `($this)` has already the new, updated values.

```
public function afterSave( $insert , $changedAttributes ) {

    if ( !$insert && isset ( $changedAttributes['status'] ) ) {
        $this->sendEmail ();
    }
    return parent::afterSave ( $insert , $changedAttributes );
}

private function sendEmail() {
    //your code to email
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    if (!$insert && array_key_exists('status_id', $changedAttributes) && $this->status_id != $changedAttributes['status_id']){
        $this->sendEmail();
    }
    return parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}

private function sendEmail() {
    //your code to email
}
```

The best way to check is an attribute has changed `afterSave()`. See `Note` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69404363/4831608)